# Fade Out 2 elements on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to fade out both a full screen overlay and an info box div when pressing the close button, for some reason the code below isn't working. Thanks in advance for your help, I am a noob when it comes to JQuery!

CSS:

```
.full_page_overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #626262;
    opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: 2147483646;
}

.cart_over {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    float: left; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2147483647;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="full_page_overlay"></div>
  <div class="cart_over">
      <a href="#" id="close_box">Close</a>
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#close_box").click(function(){
    $("#full_page_overlay").fadeOut();
    $("#cart_over").fadeOut();
})
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#close_box").click(function(){
    $(".full_page_overlay").fadeOut();
    $(".cart_over").fadeOut();
})
});
```

It's because you were using hash tags to refer to the elements - hash tags `#` look for elements by their ID's, dots `.` look for elements by their class name.

[Try jQuery](http://try.jquery.com/) is a very nice and free resource that will help you learn the basics. It's free and only thing you need is your browser.

Comment: It's kinda disappointing that jQuery can't just use a comma in the selector to fade out multiple items. But I guess it works just having them fade out with a new line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Those are classes  not Ids

```
# -->  selects Id's
. --> select classe's


$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#close_box").click(function(){
    $(".full_page_overlay").fadeOut();
    $(".cart_over").fadeOut();
})
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1360/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#close_box").click(function(){
    $(".full_page_overlay").fadeOut();
    $(".cart_over").fadeOut();
})
});
```

`full_page_overlay` and `cart_over` are **classes**, not **id**s. They should be referenced using ".", not "#".